# Gdb set a breakpoint on polymorphic methods

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

Is it possible to set a breakpoint on a method and all the methods that will override it?

Considering the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void a();
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
  virtual void a();
};
```

Is it possible to set a breakpoint on both 'a' methods using a single command other that rbreak?

Comment: missed "other that rbreak" part of the question. Any reason why rbreak is not good enough?

Comment: because you can break on methods that do not override Foo::a

Comment: you mean some method "void a()" in some arbitrary class may also be included.

Comment: yes that's the thing i would like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this right now in gdb.

I think it would be a nice addition.  However, it would be quite expensive to use.  gdb would have to read all the types in the debuginfo looking for subclasses of Foo.